# WSO2 api manager 1.7.0 - how to dynamically get the endpoint from a custom remote registry

Tags: api, dynamic, wso2, endpoint, wso2-api-manager

We have a custom service registry and I'd like to route the API call to an endpoint dynamically retrieved from that registry (in fact the registry call retrieves a list of endpoints for that service). Is there a way to do this with the API Manager 1.7.0 ? I see that the LoadBalanced configuration accepts only static endpoints.

I also looked for using the inline scripting but I did not find a proper way to call the remote registry before setting the endpoint to route to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with the custom sequences.

What you have to do is, define HTTP endpoint with properties and assign values for properties in the custom sequence.

You have to define your custom sequence and store them in registry. When publishing the api, select the proper custom sequence.

Within custom sequence, try to use class mediator/any other logic to extract your endpoint details and assign them to properties. Those properties will be used in your http endpoint definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion by creating a new api in WSO2 Api Manager, publishing it and creating a global sequence by following the docs [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Adding+Mediation+Extensions), but I was not able to make the global sequence work (at least log something on the api invocation IN flow as in the example). Any hints on this? Thanks.